# The difference between ping and pathping command?

Tags: ping, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The difference between ping and pathping command?](https://serverfault.com/questions/131052/the-difference-between-ping-and-pathping-command)

- Hi guys, today i wanna ask you a question about internet network command.
- pathping = tracert+ping, so what is the difference between ping and ping in pathping command??
- Thanks for read!^^ Goodtime!