# The difference between ping and pathping command?

Tags: networking, internet

today I want to ask you a question about internet network command `pathping` = tracert+ping, so what is the difference between ping and ping in pathping command?

Answer (score 2):

Its as you said, the Ping utility pings the address you provided, the Pathping utility does a traceroute then pings all the hops. Both pings operate in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that ping shows ICMP availability of the end point, which consist of the availability of hops in the middle and health of the endpoint. While pathping shows you health of the entire route.

Answer (score 0):

Ping shows the time it takes to get from you to the destination.

Pingpath shows time time it takes for each hop along the path from you to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any difference in the ping part of it.  When you run pathping, it does a traceroute, then pings each of the devices in the route, and reports the results of ping.

You could do this manually, and I guess at some point someone who had to do that got bored and wrote pathping to do it in a single step.

Answer (score -4):

There is a good discussion of the differences here:  http://www.google.com/search?q=pathping+vs+ping

Comment: lmgtfy is not an appropriate answer for this site. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links for reasons and alternative ways of handling simple questions.